# How do I union two datasets in Palantir Foundry within a code workbook?

Tags: python, pyspark, union, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

I need to UNION two datasets in a Code Workbook of Palantir Foundry and I'm not sure how to do that. I want to use Pyspark to do this. I'm new to Foundry, please help!

Answer (score 5):

It's the same way you would use PySpark in any other environment!

If you want to union two datasets with the same schema, say `datasetA` and `datasetB`, you could do something like

```
dataset_unioned = datasetA.unionByName(datasetB)
```

Again, this assumes (and you should probably make sure your data structure abides by this) that your two datasets have the same schema. Checkout the PySpark docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html)!